# NodeMCU Exception 28 - intermitent problem

Tags: nodemcu

I am SOMETIMES getting `exception 28` when running a web upload (over a very unstable rural internet CPE link - wifi is fine, but feed goes on and off):

```
Decoding stack results
0x40213b8c: dns_gethostbyname at core/dns.c line 1472
0x40204d95: ESP8266WiFiGenericClass::hostByName(char const*, IPAddress&, unsigned int) at /home/tony/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiGeneric.cpp line 468
0x40208d7c: HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at /home/tony/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/cores/esp8266/HardwareSerial.h line 159
0x4020519c: WiFiClient::connect(char const*, unsigned short) at /home/tony/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiClient.cpp line 98
0x40208fe0: Print::println(char const*) at /home/tony/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/cores/esp8266/Print.cpp line 190
0x402040c4: uploadAgrigis(char const*) at /home/tony/Arduino/sketches/tempo1_vs12b_Master_NodeMCU_Rain_Wind/tempo1_vs12b_Master_NodeMCU_Rain_Wind.ino line 360
0x40208f41: Print::write(char const*) at /home/tony/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/cores/esp8266/Print.h line 60
0x40208f6c: Print::println() at /home/tony/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/cores/esp8266/Print.cpp line 178
0x40204a2b: loop() at /home/tony/Arduino/sketches/tempo1_vs12b_Master_NodeMCU_Rain_Wind/tempo1_vs12b_Master_NodeMCU_Rain_Wind.ino line 258
0x402074f0: TwoWire::endTransmission() at /home/tony/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/libraries/Wire/Wire.cpp line 151
0x40203a04: BH1750_Init(int) at /home/tony/Arduino/sketches/tempo1_vs12b_Master_NodeMCU_Rain_Wind/tempo1_vs12b_Master_NodeMCU_Rain_Wind.ino line 1121
0x40209d3c: loop_wrapper() at /home/tony/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_main.cpp line 125
```

My code at line 360 is

```
if (client.connect(serverName,80)) {
```

My current strategy is to keep the wifi connection open all the time.  Should I test for connection before attempting to connect to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Exception 28 is, according to the [exception list document](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp8266_reset_causes_and_common_fatal_exception_causes_en.pdf):

> Access to invalid address

The most common cause is trying to read or write from/to a NULL pointer.

It *could* be because you have debugging turned on, and that debugging is trying to print something that didn't get returned properly from another function call (the call failed) - most likely looking up a host name (`hostByName()`) due to your intermittent internet connection.

This may sound counter intuitive, but try turning off debugging to see if that helps reduce the number of crashes.

Comment: counterintuitive makes sense.  lemme give a couple of days' benchmarking and I'll get back.  UPVOTED, pending ACCEPTANCE.

Comment: didnt solve the issue.  trying `lwIP` level change to `1.4` as per https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/4078

Comment: that didnt help either...  stumped

Comment: @tonygil You should cut your program down to the absolute minimum and add in different parts until it starts failing.

Comment: tks.  will do.  will run separate rigs with different levels of complexity.